# Authenticate external javascript requests

Tags: php, javascript, security, authentication

I have a piece of javascript that I want to implement on multiple thank-you pages of webshops to transport data to a php script (via jsonp) on a HTTPS server. Is there any way to authenticate the transport request of the external script to avoid illegal/faked requests? The easiest way would be to verify the referer e.g. by the `http_referrer` of the request. But the referrer isn't always passed by the browser. I can't use any server side script on the thank you pages to generate hashes.

Comment: What kind of "authentication" do you need? What should it authenticate?

Comment: Any one that verifies a valid request like the referer of the request to the https server or maybe a key or hash, but that is not secure because i can use javascript only on the external pages.

Comment: Crossed my mind: is it secure to fetch the url with javascript on the jsonp callback for verification? Or can that also be constructed/faked?

Comment: to fetch what url and from where? Everything that can be executed in browser can be faked.